# How to delete the respective li tag along with the button?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a list of input tags along with delete button next to it. When I click on delete button, the input tag next to it should also get deleted. Here only the button gets deleted but not the respective `li`. How do I go about this?

```
  var buttonItems = document.querySelectorAll(".deleteButton");
  var listItems = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

  for (var i = 0; i < buttonItems.length; i++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {

        buttonItems[i].addEventListener('click',function(e){
        this.remove(this)
        listItems[this].remove()
      })

    }
  }
```

Comment: Please add the HTML for your code. You will have to find a way to select the li based on the button, but we can't help you unless you tell us exactly where the li is in relation to the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get [`parentNode`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1060184317), which [`Element`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-745549614) inherits from [`Node`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247):

> In ES5

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".deleteButton").forEach(function(btn) {
  //Add listener for click event on delete button
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    //it will always return the li tag
    //beucase lit tag is parent of button..
    e.target.parentNode.remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Coffee<button class="deleteButton">Delete</button></li>
  <li>Tea <button class="deleteButton">Delete</button></li>
  <li>Milk <button class="deleteButton">Delete</button></li>
</ul>
```

> In ES6

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".deleteButton").forEach(btn => {
    //Add listener for click event on delete button
    btn.addEventListener('click', e => e.target.parentNode.remove());
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Coffee<button class="deleteButton">Delete</button></li>
  <li>Tea <button class="deleteButton">Delete</button></li>
  <li>Milk <button class="deleteButton">Delete</button></li>
</ul>
```

**References:**

- [DOM2 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/) specification - well-supported by all major browsers
- [DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/) specification - bindings between the DOM and HTML
- [DOM3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/) specification - some updates, not all supported by all major browsers
- [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) - which now has the DOM/HTML bindings in it

Comment: :-) :-) :-) :-) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use items parent to `.removeChild`.

```js
var deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".delete-button");
var grandparent;

for (var i = 0; i < deleteButtons.length; i++) {
    deleteButtons[i].addEventListener('click',function(e){
        grandparent = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
        grandparent.removeChild(e.target.parentElement);
    });
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>
Test Test 1<button class="delete-button">Delete</button>
</li>
<li>
Test Test 2<button class="delete-button">Delete</button>
</li>
<li>
Test Test 3<button class="delete-button">Delete</button>
</li>
<li>
Test Test 4<button class="delete-button">Delete</button>
</li>
<li>
Test Test 5<button class="delete-button">Delete</button>
</li>


</ul>
```

Comment: fixed. In this case the button's parent is actually the `<li>` and not the top-level list element itself, `<ul>`. So, you actually have to get the grandparent to remove the parent of the event. Hope that helps.